# How to get currently active session id (other than current user) for a website

Tags: php, session, authentication, chat

I am working on a chat application in PHP. Here I am saving one login `session_id` in to my database. When a user logout I am setting this `session_id` to null. So by this way I am getting who other users are logged in. My script is checking for every 5 second for this `session_id` & respective message if chat box is open.

Now suppose user has closed the browser itself, then how to remove him from chat-box active user list ?

When we are closing the browser, the session will get expire. Is there any thing I can trace which are all `session_id`'s currently active on a server for a particular website ?

Or Is there any way to Track all active users for chat application in PHP ? I am not getting what parameter I am missing here.

Please help me.

Comment: If you added a timestamp to the table you are updating you could just make it so it stops displaying them if it hasn't updated for a minute or so.

Comment: This can be a possible way.i was missing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly how Lucas said. Have a timestamp field calld e.g. "last_seen" and update it via AJAX in every 5 seconds (what you are doing right now anyway). Then you may think about all users that this query return as being active:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE last_seen > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 30;
```

and all others are offline (closed their browser or sth).

In the above query we assume that if user has not been seen for 30 seconds - he is offline. This value can be lower, but must be above 5 seconds (your refresh interval) because there always can be some delays in updating last_seen column.